# Vector from Dataframe Column in Julia

Tags: julia, dataframes.jl

I have a `DataFrame`

```
df = DataFrame(x = 1:3, y = 4:6)

3×2 DataFrame
 Row │ x      y     
     │ Int64  Int64 
─────┼──────────────
   1 │     1      4
   2 │     2      5
   3 │     3      6
```

How can I extract one of the columns as a `Vector`?

I know I can do `df[:,:x]` or `df.x`, but is there a way to do it with a function instead? The reason I am asking is that I work with the `Chain.jl` package and would like to do something like

```
@chain df begin
    some_manipulations_here
    pull(:x)
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do one of the the following:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(x = 1:3, y = 4:6)
3×2 DataFrame
 Row │ x      y
     │ Int64  Int64
─────┼──────────────
   1 │     1      4
   2 │     2      5
   3 │     3      6

julia> @chain df begin
       _.x
       end
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> @chain df begin
       getproperty(:x) # same as above
       end
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> @chain df begin
       getindex(!, :x) # also _[!, :x]
       end
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> @chain df begin
       getindex(:, :x) # also _[:, :x]
       end
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3
```

Probably the first option (with `_.x` is the simplest in practice.

I have shown the other options to highlight that all special syntaxes like `df.x` or `df[!, :x]` are actually function calls, and the special syntax is just a convenience.

Comment: I have added an edit with additional explanations.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so one solution is

```
@chain df begin
    some_manipulations_here
    _ |> df -> df.x
end
```

but I actually hope that someone can come up with a cleaner solution.